# How to get the canonical tag not to carry over to the blog posts?

Tags: dotnetnuke, cudnn, dnn9

DNN Ver.09.10.02

I am seeking a solution to get the canonical tag not to carry over to the blog posts. The site's blog post uses a thirty-party extension. The site built without the canonical tag. I manually inserted the canonical tag on every main page; the blog home is one of the main pages. If it does carry over, the individual post would have two canonical tags, and I do not think this is the best practice.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you manually add the tag to the "Page Header" for the page, it will follow through with all dynamically created pages.

Depending on the blog module, you could look at using a "listing" style module on the homepage and have the blog articles live on a blog page, rather than living on the homepage and not put a canonical tag on the blog page and let the blog module handle it.

Otherwise, I would remove the tag on the page that the blog is on, as there is no way for a module to remove a tag that was entered that way without custom code.

Comment: do you happen to know some custom code?